# PHP: Time slot, how much time on morning and on night?

Tags: php, time, difference

Suppose I have two strings like "08:50" (start) and "23:50" (end).
Now I know that the morning is from 06:00 to 22:00 and the night is from 22:00 and 06:00.

The question is, how can I know how much time is in the morning and how much in the night? It should be 9 hours in the morning and 1 hour 50 minutes in the night.

I have done a code, but sometimes (with particolar values) it crashes, and it loses couple of minutes:

```
function analizza_mattina_sera($result2) 
{
    $inizio_giorno = oreToMinuti("06:00");
    $fine_giorno = oreToMinuti("22:00");
    $inizio_notte = oreToMinuti("22:00");
    $fine_notte = oreToMinuti("06:00");
    $conto_minuti_giorno = "";
    $conto_minuti_notte = "";

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $data1 = strtotime($row2["anno"] 
            ."-". $row2["mese"]
            ."-". $row2["giorno"]
            ." ". $row2["ora_effettiva"]);

        $data2 = strtotime($row2["anno"]
            ."-". $row2["mese"]
            ."-". $row2["giorno"]
            ." ". $row2["ora_teorica"]);

        $differenza = (($data2 - $data1) / 3600) / (1 / 60);

        if ($row2["verso"] == "entrata") {
            $ora_usa = $row2["ora_effettiva"];
            if (oreToMinuti($ora_usa) < $inizio_giorno) {
                $conto_minuti_notte = $fine_notte - oreToMinuti($ora_usa);
            }
            if (oreToMinuti($ora_usa) > $inizio_giorno) {
                $conto_minuti_giorno = oreToMinuti($ora_usa) - $inizio_giorno;
            }
        }
        else {
            $ora_usa = $row2["ora_effettiva"];
            if (oreToMinuti($ora_usa) < $fine_giorno) {
                if (oreToMinuti($ora_usa) < $fine_notte) {
                    $conto_minuti_notte = ($fine_notte - oreToMinuti($ora_usa)) - $conto_minuti_notte;
                }
                else {
                    $conto_minuti_giorno = oreToMinuti($ora_usa) - $inizio_giorno - $conto_minuti_giorno;
                }
            }
            else {
                $conto_minuti_notte = oreToMinuti($ora_usa) - $inizio_notte;
                $conto_minuti_giorno = $fine_giorno - $conto_minuti_giorno - $inizio_giorno;
            }
        }
    }

    return str_replace("-", "", ($conto_minuti_giorno == "" ? 0 : $conto_minuti_giorno)
        ."_". ($conto_minuti_notte == "" ? 0 : $conto_minuti_notte)) ."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. With the 2 strings `08:50` and `23:50`, you need to do what?

Comment: i think it's clear: the two strings give a "time period", from - to. i need to know how much time has passed in the morning (06-22) and in the night (22-06)

Comment: Just to make explicit: What would you expect from the strings: `"08:50" (start) and "02:50" (end)`? Would you want `22:00 to 02:50` (passing through midnight) to be considered 'night'?

Comment: i'll expect as result: 13HH10mm in the morning and 4HH50mm in the night. 
and yes, 22:00 to 02:50 is night because night goes from 22:00 to 06:00

Comment: for example (another example): if i have 00:00 as start, and 06:30 as end... i would expect: 6HH0mm in night and 0HH30mm in morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (you should add some validation).

Here is how to use it, it will return an array of morning period in minutes and night period in minutes:

```
categorizePeriod('08:50', '23:50');
```

Here are the functions:

```
function minutesDiff($startTime, $endTime)
{
    $isNextDay = ($startTime > $endTime) ? 1 : 0;
    $start = explode(':', $startTime);
    $end = explode(':', $endTime);
    $diffInSeconds = abs(mktime($start[0], $start[1], 0, null, date('j'), null) - mktime($end[0], $end[1], 0, null, date('j') + $isNextDay, null));

    return floor($diffInSeconds/60);
}

function inMorning($time, array $morning)
{
    return ($morning[0] <= $time && $time <= $morning[1]);
}

function categorizePeriod($startTime, $endTime, array $morning = array('06:00', '22:00'))
{
    if ($startTime == $endTime) {
        return array(0, 0);
    } else if ($startTime > $endTime) {
        $beforeMidnight = categorizePeriod($startTime, '23:59', $morning);
        $afterMidnight = categorizePeriod('00:00', $endTime, $morning);

        return array(
                $beforeMidnight[0] + $afterMidnight[0] + (int)inMorning('00:00', $morning),
                $beforeMidnight[1] + $afterMidnight[1] + (int)!inMorning('00:00', $morning),
        );
    }

    if (inMorning($startTime, $morning) && inMorning($endTime, $morning)) {
        return array(
                minutesDiff($startTime, $endTime),
                0
        );
    } elseif (!inMorning($startTime, $morning) && !inMorning($endTime, $morning)) {
        return array(
                0,
                minutesDiff($startTime, $endTime)
        );
    } elseif (inMorning($startTime, $morning) && !inMorning($endTime, $morning)) {
        return array(
                minutesDiff($startTime, $morning[1]),
                minutesDiff($morning[1], $endTime)
        );
    } elseif (!inMorning($startTime, $morning) && inMorning($endTime, $morning)) {
        return array(
                minutesDiff($morning[0], $endTime),
                minutesDiff($startTime, $morning[0])
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.. I have converted to hours..

Say for e.g.

```
Start - 4.30 and End - 21.30 then morning 15.5 hours and night 1.5 hours
Start - 4.30 and End - 22.30 then morning 16 hours and night 2 hours
Start - 6.30 and End - 21.30 then morning 15 hours and night 0 hours
Start - 6.30 and End - 22.30 then morning 15.5 hours and night 0.5 hours
```

Following is the script may be helpful to you.

```
        <?php
    //Get the timeslote how many hours spent in the morning and how many hours spent in the night
    $start = "00:00";
    $end = "00:00";
    $morningSlote = "06:00 - 22:00";
    $nightSlote = "22:00 - 06:00";
    $startTime = strtotime($start);
    $endTime = strtotime($end);
    $startDate = date("m/d/Y");
    $endDate = date("m/d/Y");
    if($startTime > $endTime) {
        //Date will be changed
        //i.e. 11.30 PM - 2.30 AM
        //i.e. 11.30 PM - 6.20 PM
        $startDate = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime($start));
        $endDate = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime("+1 day".$end));                
    } else if($endTime > $startTime) {
        //No date will be changed
        //i.e. 2.30 AM - 11.30 PM
        //i.e. 2.30 AM - 6.30 AM        
        $startDate = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime($start));
        $endDate = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime($end));             
    }
    $output = getCorrectTimeslote($startDate, $endDate, $morningSlote, $nightSlote);

    echo "<br>spent in the morning: ".$output["morningSession"]." Hours";
    echo "<br>spent in the night: ".$output["nightSession"]." Hours";


    function getCorrectTimeslote($startDate, $endDate, $morningSlote, $nightSlote) {        
        $output = array();
        $morningSloteStart = "";
        $morningSloteEnd = "";
        $nightSloteStart = "";
        $nightSloteEnd = "";

        $morningSloteExplodedResult = array();
        if(strpos($morningSlote,"-") !== false) {
            $morningSloteExplodedResult = explode("-",$morningSlote);
            $morningSloteStart = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime(trim($morningSloteExplodedResult[0])));
            $morningSloteEnd = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime(trim($morningSloteExplodedResult[1])));
        }

        $nightSloteExplodedResult = array();
        if(strpos($nightSlote,"-") !== false) {
            $nightSloteExplodedResult = explode("-",$nightSlote);
            $nightSloteStart = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime(trim($nightSloteExplodedResult[0])));
            $nightSloteEnd = date("m/d/Y H:i:s",strtotime("+1 day".trim($nightSloteExplodedResult[1])));
        }           

        if((isset($morningSloteStart) && !empty($morningSloteStart)) && (isset($morningSloteEnd) && !empty($morningSloteEnd)) && (isset($nightSloteStart) && !empty($nightSloteStart)) && (isset($nightSloteEnd) && !empty($nightSloteEnd))) {

            $morningSession = 0;
            $nightSession = 0;              
            if($endDate >= $startDate) {                
                if($morningSloteStart >= $startDate) {              
                    //No date will be changed
                    if($endDate > $nightSloteStart) {                       
                        //i.e. 2.30 AM - 11.30 PM                       
                        if($morningSloteStart > $startDate) {
                            $nightSession = ago($morningSloteStart,$startDate);
                        }
                        $morningSession = ago($morningSloteEnd,$morningSloteStart);                 
                        $nightSession += ago($endDate,$nightSloteStart);
                    } else if($endDate >= $morningSloteStart) {                     
                        //i.e. 2.30 AM - 6.30 AM                                                
                        //i.e. 2.30 AM - 6.30 AM                                                
                        $nightSession = ago($morningSloteStart,$startDate);
                        $morningSession = ago($endDate,$morningSloteStart);
                    } else {
                        $morningSession = 0;
                        $nightSession = ago($endDate,$startDate);
                    }
                } else if($endDate >= $nightSloteEnd) {                 

                    //Date will be changed
                    if($morningSloteStart < $startDate && $endDate < $nightSloteStart) {
                        //23:30 - 22:30
                        $morningSloteStart = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day".$morningSloteStart));
                        $morningSloteEnd = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day".$morningSloteEnd));
                        $nightSloteStart = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day".$nightSloteStart));
                        $nightSession = ago($morningSloteStart,$startDate);
                        $morningSession = ago($morningSloteStart,$morningSloteEnd);
                        $nightSession += ago($endDate,$nightSloteStart);
                    } else {
                        //Removing date addition
                        $endDate = date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime("-1 day".$endDate));
                        //i.e. 11.30 PM - 6.00 AM && 6.00 AM - 6.20 PM
                        $nightSession = ago($startDate,$nightSloteEnd);                 
                        $morningSession = ago($endDate,$morningSloteStart);
                    }
                } else {                    
                    if($startDate >= $morningSloteStart && $nightSloteStart >= $endDate) {
                        //i.e. 6.30 AM - 9.30 AM
                        $nightSession = 0;
                        $morningSession = ago($endDate,$startDate);
                    } else if($startDate >= $morningSloteStart && $nightSloteStart < $startDate) {                      
                        //i.e. 22.30 PM - 23.59                     
                        $nightSession = ago($startDate,$endDate);
                        $morningSession = 0;
                    } else if($startDate >= $morningSloteStart && $nightSloteStart < $endDate) {

                        //i.e. 5.30 PM - 23.59                      
                        $nightSession = ago($nightSloteStart,$endDate);
                        $morningSession = ago($startDate,$nightSloteStart);
                    } else {                        
                        //Date will be changed
                        //i.e. 11.30 PM - 6.00 AM && 6.00 AM - 2.30 AM
                        $morningSession = 0;
                        $nightSession = ago($endDate,$startDate);
                    }
                }
            }       

        }

        $output["morningSession"] = $morningSession/60; //hours
        $output["nightSession"] = $nightSession/60; //hours 
        return $output;     
    }       


    function ago($datetime1,$datetime2) {
        $date1 = new DateTime($datetime1);
        $date2 = new DateTime($datetime2);
        $interval = $date1->diff($date2);       
        $minutes = 0;
        if($interval->days >= 1) $minutes += $interval->days * 24 * 60;     
        if($interval->h >= 1) $minutes += $interval->h * 60;
        if($interval->i >= 1) $minutes += $interval->i;
        return $minutes;
    }
?>
```

Comment: whoops! founded a problem... try with start: 00:00 and end 00:21 it return array(2) { ["morningSession"]=> int(339) ["nightSession"]=> int(360) } instead of array(2) { ["morningSession"]=> int(0) ["nightSession"]=> int(21) }

Comment: nope, more problem than before: if you try with start 17:31end 23:59 it will return 0 in morning and 6h28m in night!!! but it must be 4h29m in morning and 1h59m in night

Comment: This case is not working:
- Night shift start at 22:00
- Night shift ends at 07:00
- Working hours (20:00 to 10:00 next day)

**Obtained result: **
- Night hours: 11
- Day hours: 3

**Expected result:**
- Night hours: 9
- Day hours: 5